# Google Chrome new content behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I know that Google Chrome has this effect for tabs where they light up when new content appears on the page and you are not viewing that tab currently.It usually shows up on sites like grooveshark.If you know what i am talking about i would like to simulate this effect if anyone knows how.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the page title (`document.title`). That's all there is to it.